# I can't bring the div when I click the button mutiple times using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

When you click on bar icon **more than once**, you can't bring the cross icon.

When you click on the bar icon, a cross icon appears. When you click on the new cross icon, bar icon appears. So far so good. But when you click on the bar icon again, nothing happens.

```js
var barsIcon = document.getElementById("bars-icon");
var crossOG;

barsIcon.addEventListener("click", function() {
  barsIcon.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-times');
  barsIcon.setAttribute('id', 'cross-icon');

  var crossIcon = document.getElementById('cross-icon');
  crossOG = crossIcon;

  crossIcon.addEventListener("click", function() {
    crossIcon.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-bars fa-x');
    crossIcon.setAttribute('id', 'bars-icon');
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css">
</head>

  <div>
    <i class="fas fa-bars" id="bars-icon" style="flex-grow: 1;"></i>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not the right way to bind an event. Do not use event binding in nested functions. This is not a good practise

```js
var menuIcon = document.getElementById("icon");
var toggled = false;
var crossOG;

menuIcon.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(!toggled){
    menuIcon.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-times');
    toggled = true;
  }
  else{
    menuIcon.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-bars fa-x');
    toggled = false;
  }
    
});
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css">
</head>

  <div>
    <i class="fas fa-bars" id="icon" style="flex-grow: 1;"></i>
  </div>
```

And do not change an item id.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't mess around with the IDs of your elements e.g. changing it at runtime.
Better add both icon elements to the DOM initially and toggle their visibliy using the **display** property.

```js
var barsIcon = document.getElementById("bars-icon");
barsIcon.addEventListener("click", function() {
  barsIcon.style.display = "none";
  crossIcon.style.display = "initial";

});

var crossIcon = document.getElementById('cross-icon');
crossIcon.addEventListener("click", function() {
  barsIcon.style.display = "initial";
  crossIcon.style.display = "none";
});
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css">
</head>

<div>
  <i class="fas fa-bars" id="bars-icon" style="flex-grow: 1;"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-times" id="cross-icon" style="flex-grow: 1;display:none"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem bhushanoff - glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to change the id of a DOM element, especially for one that you attached an event listener onto. A solution would be to use two icons and display/hide them according to which is clicked.

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css">

</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <i class="fas fa-bars" id="bars-icon" style="flex-grow: 1;"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-times" id="cross-icon" style="flex-grow: 1; display: none;"></i>
  </div>
</body>
```

```js
var barsIcon = document.getElementById("bars-icon");
var crossIcon = document.getElementById("cross-icon");


barsIcon.addEventListener("click", function() {
    barsIcon.style.display = 'none';
    crossIcon.style.display = 'block';

});

crossIcon.addEventListener("click", function() {
    crossIcon.style.display = 'none';
    barsIcon.style.display = 'block';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping your current state on your **tag node in custom attribute data-attr** instead of creating a javascript **variable**.

Read the current state of HTML node and work accordingly.

```js
var barsicon = document.getElementById("bars-icon");
barsicon.addEventListener("click", baricon);
function baricon() {
 if(barsicon.getAttribute('data-attr') == "bars"){
   barsicon.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-times');
   barsicon.setAttribute('data-attr', 'cross');
 }else{
   barsicon.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-bars');
   barsicon.setAttribute('data-attr', 'bars');  
 }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css">
<div>
    <i class="fas fa-bars" data-attr="bars" id="bars-icon" style="flex-grow: 1;"></i>
  </div>
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank You, @Growyour GK!